# glob - set relative path root directory

Tags: php, path, root, relative-path, glob

I'm having some trouble with glob in php and although I did some research, I just couldn't seem to find an answer to my problem.

First of all to my directory structure:

```
/ (root)
 /images (folder)
       - gallery/ (sub folder containing image files)
 /pages (folder)
       - gallery.php
```

I want to access the subfolder 'gallery' in the folder 'images'. So: In my gallery.php file I got the following line:

```
$images = glob("/images/gallery/*.*");
```

And this doesn't work.

What does work is, if I change the path to "**../**"

```
$images = glob("../images/gallery/*.*");
```

or if I change the code to:

```
define('BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$images = glob(BASE."/images/gallery/*.*");
```

Unfortunatly the sourcecode then shows some info I'm not sure I want to actually make public

```
e.g.    
/home/scecjwkh/htdocs/images/gallery/3.JPG
```

I hope the information I provided is enough to actually understand my problem. Not sure why I have so much trouble with a relative path o.O

Thank you in advance,
Stuben

Comment: When you give a path starting with a slash (`/`), it's considered as an absolute path from your media/disk root dir, and not relative to the application root dir. BTW, what are you trying to use `glob` for? Maybe if you explain that, you can improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you usually do is use `__DIR__` to build relative paths from the current script's folder. You can also use `__DIR__` to know what part to cut from the final paths, because you should know where in the project your current file is and thus know where the root is relative to it.

`$images = glob(__DIR__."/../images/gallery/*.*");` gets the image list without caring about [current working dir](http://php.net/getcwd), after which you can use `realpath(__DIR__.'/..')` to figure out how much to snip from each file path.